# Please help me to get data from ADS1247IPWR

Tags: adc, spi, rtd

please help me. I tried many times and many designs to reslow my problem. My ADC1247IPWR is measuring always the same value. Perhaps looks like I configured it wrong. My valve is changing if I use something another settings, so seems all okay with my design. For example if I unconnect AIN3 then my ADC code going from 58302 to 6. Please help me, this is my first ADC in life. I using PT100 connected by 3-wire sheme:

[image]

Code:

```c
#include "main.h"
#include "settings.h"
#include "string.h"

// SPI handler
extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
uint8_t ads1247_is_configured = 0;

// Constants for ADS1247 configuration
const uint8_t ads1247_mux0_addr = 0x01; // Address for MUX0 register
const uint8_t ads1247_mux1_addr = 0x02; // Address for MUX1 register
const uint8_t ads1247_sys0_addr = 0x03; // Address for SYS0 register
const uint8_t ads1247_idac0_addr = 0x0A; // Address for IDAC0 register
const uint8_t ads1247_idac1_addr = 0x0B; // Address for IDAC1 register
const uint8_t ads1247_read_cmd = 0x01; // Read command for ADS1247

const uint8_t ads1247_mux0_value = 0x66; // AIN0(+) - AIN1(-) inputs, differential mode, gain = 8, PGA enabled
const uint8_t ads1247_mux1_value = 0x00; // Internal reference off, enable MUX1, disable MUX2
const uint8_t ads1247_sys0_value = 0x04; // 20 SPS, normal mode, continuous conversion mode
const uint8_t ads1247_idac0_value = 0x02; // IDAC0 output to AIN0, 500 µA
const uint8_t ads1247_idac1_value = 0x72; // IDAC1 output to AIN2, IDAC2 output to AIN3


// Function to read data from ADS1247
uint32_t ads_read_data() {

    static uint32_t adc_code = 0;
    uint8_t read_buffer[3];
    uint32_t wait_count = 0;

    // Set configuration to ADS1247
    if (ads1247_is_configured == 0) {
        // Untake from reset stage
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RESET_GPIO_Port, RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(16);

        // Configure MUX0 and MUX1 registers for temperature measurement
        uint8_t mux0_config[3] = {ads1247_mux0_addr, ads1247_mux0_value, 0x00};
        uint8_t mux1_config[3] = {ads1247_mux1_addr, ads1247_mux1_value, 0x00};

        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, mux0_config, sizeof(mux0_config), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, mux1_config, sizeof(mux1_config), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        // Configure SYS0 register for PGA gain, oscillator, and clock settings
        uint8_t sys0_config[3] = {ads1247_sys0_addr, ads1247_sys0_value, 0x00};
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, sys0_config, sizeof(sys0_config), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        // Configure IDAC0 register
        uint8_t idac0_config[3] = {ads1247_idac0_addr, ads1247_idac0_value, 0x00};
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, idac0_config, sizeof(idac0_config), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        // Configure IDAC1 register for temperature measurement
        uint8_t idac1_config[3] = {ads1247_idac1_addr, (ads1247_idac1_value << 4) | ads1247_idac1_value, 0x00};
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, idac1_config, sizeof(idac1_config), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        ads1247_is_configured = 1;
    }

    // Send read command to ADS1247
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)&ads1247_read_cmd, sizeof(ads1247_read_cmd), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    // Wait for DRDY pin to go low to indicate adc code is ready to be read
    while (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SPI1_DRDY_PB0_GPIO_Port, SPI1_DRDY_PB0_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET) {
        wait_count++;
        if (wait_count > 100) { // If the device is not ready after 10 second, exit the function
            ads1247_is_configured = 0;
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RESET_GPIO_Port, RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_Delay(16);
            return 0;
        }
        HAL_Delay(10);
    }

    // Read data from ADS1247
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY); // Read 3 bytes (24 bits) of data with a maximal timeout

    // Copy 3 bytes of data into a 32-bit variable using memcpy()
    memcpy(&adc_code, read_buffer, sizeof(adc_code));

    // Return ADC code
    return adc_code;
}

void PT100() {
    if (Holding_Registers_Database[5] == 1) {
        // Read data from ADS1247
        Input_Registers_Database[0] = ads_read_data() / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what is connected to J2. Where is the GND path of the sensor?

Comment: 4 wire RTD PT100. No, temperature sensor have no GND.

Comment: The datasheet says, that the internal reference must be active for using the current sources. Try MUX0 = 0x01 and MUX1 = 0x20.